# htaccess redirect subpages from old category to same pages in different category

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all my pages from categery old to category new.

http://mywebsite.com/old/page1 to http://mywebsite.com/new/page1
http://mywebsite.com/old/page2 to http://mywebsite.com/new/page2

This is not work

```
RewriteRule ^old/(.*) http://mywebsite.com/new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution

> RedirectMatch 301 /old/(.*) /new/$1